# sylius how to get container inside a form type class without use of constructor?

Tags: symfony, sylius

i want to use the service container inside a form type class, but $this->container always return null.

here the class of my form

```
<?php

namespace St\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ShippingMethodType as BaseShippingMethodType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;

class ShippingMethodType extends BaseShippingMethodType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', ['required' => false])
        ;

        var_dump($this->container);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event)  {

            $data = $event->getData();

            $tools = $this->container->get('a_tools');
            $tools->saveImage($data);
        });
    }

}
```

and here the service for this form, i use the setter injection method, but it seem not working because the var_dump of $this->container in the class return null

```
a_shipping_method.form.type:
    class: St\AppBundle\Form\Type\ShippingMethodType
    calls:
      - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: sylius_shipping_method }
```

why the setter injection doesn't work for this case ?

Comment: I am guessing your code is using the new operator? $shippingMethodType = new ShippingMethodType();

Comment: In principle, it is possible to pass a variable to a form type via its options. If `a_tools` is a parameter in `parameters.yml`, it is available in a controller with `$tools = $this->container->getParameter('a_tools');`.  The variable `$tools` can then be set in the form type `configureOptions()` with `$tools = null,`.  Once this is set up, the form can then be called with `ShippingMethodType()::class, ['tools' => $tools]`.  Or something close to this :)!

Comment: the form is created by the resource controller the updateAction: $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $resource); a_tools is a service